# How to define a custom ORDER BY in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I need output in following order(firstly, group by last 3 letters and then arrange in order based on the first 3 digits)

```
ColumnA

001_eng
004_eng
002_chn
003_usa
```

But order by ColumnA gives me

```
ColumnA

001_eng
002_chn
003_usa
004_eng
```

This is just sample data. I have hundreds of entries in this format and the values keep changing everyday. So, specifying all the entries inside the field is not a feasible option.
I'm not sure of how to use FIELD() in my case.

Comment: what is your order criteria? It does not seem clear from your expected output. You aren't sorting language or country prefix (e.g. eng, chn, usa, etc) by alphabetic order, so you would need to explain how that is prioritized.

The only order criteria that is clear is that per language prefix, you are then ordering by numeric id in ascending order (e.g. for eng: 001, 004, etc)

Comment: How about normalising your data?

Comment: @strawberry : I cannot alter the tables as I'm just a tester and i shouldn't be changing table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`SUBSTRING_INDEX`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) in case all `ColumnA` values are formatted like in the sample data:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY FIELD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ColumnA, '_', -1), 'eng', 'chn', 'usa'),
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(ColumnA, '_', 1)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ba56/2)

Comment: your query doesn't produce the expected output for Nitish. He hasn't specified how the language prefix is prioritized.

Comment: @JonathonOgden Yes you are right. I have fixed it now.

Comment: This was exactly what i wanted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use FIELD:

```
select *
from tablename
order by
  FIELD(ColumnA, '001_eng', '004_eng', '002_chn', '003_usa')
```

(please be careful if ColumnA is not in the list the field function will return 0 and the rows will be put on top)

or you can use CASE WHEN:

```
select *
from tablename
order by
  case
    when ColumnA='001_eng' then 1
    when ColumnA='004_eng' then 2
    when ColumnA='002_chn' then 3
    when ColumnA='003_usa' then 4
    else 5
  end
```

or you can use a different languages table where you specify the order:

```
id | name    | sortorder
1  | 001_eng | 1
2  | 002_chn | 3
3  | 003_usa | 4
4  | 004_eng | 2
```

then you can use a join

```
select t.*
from
  tablename t inner join languages l
  on t.lang_id = l.id
order by
  l.sortorder
```

(with proper indexes this would be the better solution with optimal performances)

Comment: @NitishVasu fthiella's last solution would let your queries using custom ordering to grow easier without hardcoding the comparisons in a `CASE` or `FIELD` statement every time a new value needs to be compared. You can also trim down fthiella's table by setting a sort order per language prefix (e.g. eng, chn, usa) and not the full key (e.g. 001_eng, 004_eng, etc)

Answer (score 0):

you can use substring() and get order by

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(ColumnA, -7, 3);
```